# Dictionary KeyCollection Strangeness

Tags: c#, .net

I have a mysterious situation involving a dictionary where I enumerate keys from the dictionary, but the dictionary doesn't contain some of the keys it says it contains.

```
Dictionary<uint, float> dict = GetDictionary(); // Gets values, 6268 pairs
foreach(uint key in dict.Keys)
{
   if (!dict.ContainsKey(key))
      Console.WriteLine("Wat? "+key);
}
```

The above will print two of the 6268 keys. Nothing special about those two keys, both positive values smaller than Int32.MaxValue (369099203 and 520093968).

A check on the counts reveals this:

```
Console.WriteLine(dict.Count);                           // 6268
Console.WriteLine(dict.Keys.Count());                    // 6268
Console.WriteLine(dict.Keys.Count(dict.Keys.Contains));  // 6266
```

This is <strike>single threaded</strike> .NET4 code running under .NET4.5 CLR. The dictionary is a vanilla `Dictionary<uint, float>` i.e. **there is no custom equality comparer**. I assume there is a hash problem occuring because of the uint/int difference, but shouldn't the `ContainsKey(key)` be guaranteed to be true for all keys returned in the Key collection of the dictionary? Especially when you ONLY look at the KeyCollection object as in the lower code snippet, there the total count and the count of contained objects is off, which feels like an odd `ICollection` behavior.

**Edit:**

As expected there appears to be a reasonable explanation: the collection *was* modified earlier by two concurrent threads during its initialization. When something "sometimes breaks" , it is a threadnig issue, and sure enough. Accessing a dict from several threads can apparently upset the internal state enough for it to be kust semi-functioning for the remainder of its lifetime, but without causing any exceptions.

I'm going to switch to a concurrent dictionary, and probably delete this question. Thanks.

Comment: Can you construct a complete example which demonstrates this?

Comment: What does GetDictionary() actually look like

Comment: Is this line correct: `Console.WriteLine(dict.Keys.Count(dict.Keys.Contains));`?

Comment: @talles yes, this is a valid C# code, It uses method group  syntax instead of lambda. Semantically the same as `dict.Keys.Count(key => dict.Keys.Contains(key))`

Comment: @JonSkeet I can't produce a complete simple example, even by hard coding the dictionary to the exact same data that was in the real code when I stopped at the corrupt state. Posting the problem on stackoverflow has also mysteriously resolved the bug in my production code, when run the next time (is there a Heisenbug-like expression for this?).

Comment: It's a HeisenOverflowBug.

Comment: Actually, it still occurs intermittently, with a dictionary containing the same set of keys sometimes being ok, sometimes not. I'll try to dig into what causes it (the sequence of adding and removing values seems to be involved).

Comment: @DDJKRAZE the method that creates the data is sadly too complicated to  present. Like I said there is nothing weird, I create the dictionary myself and add/remove values from it (in a long intricate process). I tried snapshoting the corrupt dict and hard code it into a simple repro, but that does then *not* show the odd behavior. I'll try to create a complete reproduction.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough rep to comment - but I did try to reproduce your issue to no avail.  I will suggest that you post how GetDictionary() is working and also I would suggest NOT iterating through a dictionary like that, do below instead and see if that seems to fix it:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<uint, float> pair in dict)
    Console.WriteLine("[" + pair.Key + "]=" + pair.Value);
```

Comment: Thanks, trying to reproduce now it I can't, so I think I'll delete my question until I can reproduce it completely.

Comment: No need to delete the question - I am still curious if there's a way to break a dictionary that way, could be useful knowledge.

Comment: I won't delete it just yet (when I said that I thought I had just had a one-off freak cosmic-ray memory corruption or something) but now at least I can reproduce it intermittently in the production code, so I'll keep trying to create a simple example that reproduces it.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a chance of that GetDictionary() adds custom key equality comparer when constructing the dictionary? If so, the problem may be related to the comparer implementation.

Answer (score 0):

**Important note:** When I refer to `GetHashCode` throughout this post, I am referring to the result of `IEqualityComparer<T>.GetHashCode`. By default, the dictionary will use `EqualityComparer<T>.Default`, which will return the result of calling `GetHashCode` on the key itself. However, you can provide a specific implementation of `IEqualityComparer<T>` at the time the dictionary is created to use a different behavior.

This can happen if the result of `GetHashCode` for a key changes between the time the value is added to the dictionary and the point where you enumerated the keys. When you enumerated the keys, it returns the keys for all populated "buckets" in the array. However, when you look up a *specific* key it recalculates the *expected* bucket from the result of `GetHashCode` for the key. If the hash code changed, then the actual location of the key/value pair in the dictionary's buckets and the expected location may no longer be the same, in which case `Contains` would return false.

You should make sure that the result of `GetHashCode` for the keys in the dictionary can't change after a value is added to the dictionary for the key.

Comment: Yes, but this should hardly be possible for immutable value types (`uint` in this case).

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes The implementation of `UInt32.GetHashCode` is constant for a key, but there is no requirement that a dictionary use the default `IEqualityComparer<uint>`.

Comment: If the key was a reference type, then the value of a key already added to the dictionary could be changed. This is not the case here. As long as the key doesn't change, any comparer should always return the same hash code. The OP didn't use a custom equality comparer.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes The OP said the issue appeared when 1) using `Dictionary<uint, float>` (which I assume is the one provided by .NET 4.0 in mscorlib), 2) didn't use a custom `IEqualityComparer<uint>`, 3) the code is what's listed in the original post, 4) is executing single-threaded, 5) results in the stated output. One of these is not true, the only one of which provides an interesting answer here is #2 (especially since the dictionary construction is hidden behind an opaque `GetDictionary` call).

Comment: Yes, we really need to know what `GetDictionary` does. What is the point of encapsulating `new Dictionary<uint, float>()` in a method?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes this is the interesting bit: if I JUST encapsulate the creation of the dictionary and the addition of just the data values, the resulting dictionary is correct. So I can't show a working repro, in my production code I just "have" a dictionary that behaves like this. My question is: what could I have done to make the dictionary become like that?

Comment: @AndersForsgren: It's very hard to guess what an unknown code does! How is the dictionary instantiated? How are the values added?

Comment: It is created by "new Dictionary<uint, float>()" so not in external code, and no custom comparer. Values are added by the dict[key] = val, and removed by dict.Remove(key).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar weird behaviours with System.Uri too.

It turned to be an architecture mismatch between the key that was stored in the dictionary and the key that I was using to lookup. In particular, the Uri stored in the dictionary was 32bit, while I was looking for a 64bit one. Obviously, since **GetHashcode() is not granted to be equal between different architectures**, the dictionary was unable to match the keys.